# Trying to Aggregation ElasticSearch with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to group a document for a specific field, but I'm doing something wrong. The document is not returning with aggregation

**REQUEST**

```
return client.search(
        {
            index: "xx",
            type: "cars",
            fields: ["Marca.id", "Marca.nome"],
            size: 10,
            body:{
                aggs : {
                    marcas : {
                        terms : { 
                            field : 'Marca.id' 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                 
        })
```

**RESPONSE**

```
"hits": [
{
  "_index": "xx",
  "_type": "cars",
  "_id": "xx",
  "_score": 1,
  "fields": {
    "Marca.id": [
      xx
    ],
    "Marca.nome": [
      "HONDA"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index": "dbcatalogo",
  "_type": "cars",
  "_id": "xx",
  "_score": 1,
  "fields": {
    "Marca.id": [
      xx
    ],
    "Marca.nome": [
      "HONDA"
    ]
  }
},
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. Can you explain? The aggregations are missing?

Comment: The aggregations can be found after the hits and not within them, it's another section of the response.

Comment: Thats the problem, aggregations are not in my response. Any idea whats happening?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?